# Environment variables in yml

Tags: java, yaml

I want to pass an environment variable to a yml resource file. I don't know which notation I should use. I tried:

```yaml
data:
  id: '{{system.id}}'
```

I load this yaml into a Java application, but I'm not using Spring - it's not an `application.yml`. This yaml has more static fields, which I don't want to be parametrized through environment variables. Is there any way to achieve that?

Environment variable for this example is set as `SYSTEM_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

YAML - is just a format. By itself it doesn't handle variables substitutions like this. Spring boot does that as a "feature", but if you say that you don't use Spring at all, then you'll have to resolve the data from env. variables by yourself.
In this case it pretty much depends on how do you read the YAML file.

In a nutshell, the algorithm should be as follows:

1. Read The Yaml file from the filesystem "as if" its a regular text file (don't parse it yet)
2. Apply the template engine:
   Examples of template engines like this are: mustache, freemarker and there are many others. All of them will accept the yaml string as one parameter and all the environment variables as another parameter. They will execute the actual substitution and will return another string - a yaml with substituted values.
   In the documentation of the template engine its usually written how should we define the 'parameter' in the file. Some engines will allow defining your custom parameter syntax. So it can be `{{SOMETHING}}` for example.
3. Now this yaml file should be given to the yaml parser that you already use.